# VS code formatting items on a new line

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, formatting, svelte

Im using javascript. Code inside of function calls and arrays (seems to be anything seperated by a comma) is put onto new lines during the formatting. Im looking to stop this. Example of what happens is below. I want it to saty as "Before". Im happy to get a formatter, I am currently just using in built VScode formatting.

Before:

```js
let positions = ["1. Safelane", "2. Midlane", "3. Offlane", "4. Soft Support", "5. Hard Support"].
```

After:

```js
let positions = [
    "1. Safelane",
    "2. Midlane",
    "3. Offlane",
    "4. Soft Support",
    "5. Hard Support",
];
```

I have gone into settings. Searched "format" and seen lots of settings. I have looked thourgh all extension options including typescript and svelt. As I am using svelte.

It is specifically code between below tags. I am searching and searching but can not find anything.

Comment: do you use prettier extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Svelte extension uses [Prettier](https://prettier.io/), which is an opinionated little piece of ... software.

Your options are:

- Not using formatting provided by the extension
  (`"svelte.plugin.svelte.format.enable": false`)
- Accepting most everything it does

For the JS parts you can also use a workaround to employ the default formatter:

- Change document language to HTML
- Select code in `<script>`
- Execute `Format Selection` command
- Change document language back to Svelte

(If you format everything with the default HTML formatter, the Svelte syntax will not be treated correctly.)

Comment: ok coolies. I am looking into the default formatter now. I have disabled the formatting of svelt via the setting you mentioned. Thank you human with knowledge!